# IBM Cloud Private CE - Unauthorized Access to Catalog

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, ibm-cloud-private, private-cloud

I have installed ICP CE 2.1.0 on a google cloud VM and the installation has gone well-no errors in installation process. When accessing the GUI I am able to see deployments and services but as soon as I access any part of the Catalog I get a blank white page with the text:

```
{"statusCode":401,"details":"Unexpected response code 401 from request:\nGET https://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8443/console/api/v1/header?serviceId=catalog-ui&dev=false&accessUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fxx.xxx.xxx.xx%3A8443* ...... }
```

I have tried killing the individual pods but I get same error. When looking a the pod logs for the catalog-ui I have error 500 messages.

Has anyone experienced this or can tell my why this is the case? Understand that a cloud VM is not the best use case maybe but it should work?

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the version level of ICP? Your post mentioned "ICP CE 2.1.0" but if you can check the user icon (top right corner) and click About, we should be able to see the full version details.

Reason for asking is that, at the 2100 level there was an intermittent catalog issue just like you describe.  Generally it was caused by resource constraints on the k8s.

Details for ICP 2103, which is the latest available release:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_2.1.0.3/getting_started/whats_new.html